# MountVolume.setup failed for volume “…”: mount failed: exit status 32

Tags: mount, nfs

My OS is Ubuntu, using openshift, and one pod keep pending, because nfs server cannot be mounted (nfs server is able to be mounted by mannually using command line, but cannot be mounted from the Pod)

I have installed nfs-common, so it's not the root cause. I trying to install nfs-utils, but I was failed, the error message is:

E: Unable to locate package: nfs-utils.

I also tried libnfs12 and libnfs-utils, they were the same as nfs-utils. I also used apt-get install upgade and update to solve the package locating problem, but they were useless.

I'm going to show the yaml file for connecting the nfs server

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-test01
  lables:
    disktype: baas
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    path: /baas
    server: 9.111.140.47
    readOnly: false
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
```

after using "oc describe pod/mypod" for the pending Pod, below is the feedback:

```
Warning  FailedMount  14s  kubelet, localhost  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pv-test01" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/origin/cluster-up/root/openshift.local.clusterup/openshift.local.volumes/pods/267db6f2-d875-11e9-80ba-005056bc3ce0/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/pv-test01 --scope -- mount -t nfs 9.111.140.47:/baas /var/lib/origin/cluster-up/root/openshift.local.clusterup/openshift.local.volumes/pods/267db6f2-d875-11e9-80ba-005056bc3ce0/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/pv-test01
Output: Running scope as unit run-28094.scope.
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on 9.111.140.47:/baas,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

so how can I mount to nfs server from the Pod?

Comment: You haven't said what OS & release you are running, there is no package titled `nfs-utils` in any supported Ubuntu (or flavor of Ubuntu) - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=nfs-utils  so what are you running?  `libnfs-utils` exists for some releases, but what OS (*& release*) are you using?

Comment: Hi guiverc, thanks for replying, I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: What release of Ubuntu, packages vary on release which is why we need OS & release.  The url I gave will answer your *libnfs-utils* question, we can't provide more until we know release as release is key to using url.

Comment: you are right, nfs-utils may not be the package being required, because Ubuntu doesn't support it. I installed nfs-commons anyway, and be able to mount manually from command line, but not sure why the Pod is pending because of mounting to nfs server